# How to preg_replace from indentifier to end of text with CR(LF) characters

Tags: php, preg-replace, carriage-return, linefeed

I'm trying to split a piece of text (actually html) into two pieces, a top and bottom part. An 'identifier' (<--#SPLIT#-->) in the text marks the position to split.

To get the upper part I have the following preg_replace that does work:

```
$upper = preg_replace('/<--#SPLIT#-->(\s*.*)*/', '', $text);
```

This leaves me with all the text that comes before '<--#SPLIT#-->'.

To get the lower part I came up with the following preg_replace that does NOT work correctly:

```
$lower = preg_replace('/(\s*.*)*<--#SPLIT#-->/', '', $text);
```

This returns an empty string.

How can I fix the second one?

Comment: Can you give a sample input and what you want outputted? This can probably be done with one regex.

Comment: is there only one `<--#SPLIT#-->` in the text? And is `<--#SPLIT#-->` a literal string?

Comment: Why preg_replace? Why not preg_split?

Comment: Try this: $lower = preg_replace('/(.*)<--#SPLIT#-->/', '', $text);

Comment: or explode('<--#SPLIT#-->',$text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use:

```
explode('<--#SPLIT#-->', $text);
```

Example code:

```
$text = 'Foo bar<--#SPLIT#-->Baz fez';
$temp = explode('<--#SPLIT#-->', $text);
$upper = $temp[0];
$lower = (count($temp > 1) ? $temp[1] : '');

// $upper == 'Foo bar'
// $lower == 'Baz fez'
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Thanks.